# How to get a nice code to insert pictures on the right?

Tags: floats, pstricks

In my document must insert many pictures. I don't know how to get a nice code? I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{color, graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
Type a quote from the document or the summary of an interesting point. You can position the text box anywhere in the document. Use the Drawing Tools tab to change the formatting of the pull quote text box.
Type a quote from the document or the summary of an interesting point. 
\caption{}\label{fig:*1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\textwidth}
\centering
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.56,0.5)(0.88,4.07)
\psline(-1.9,3.57)(-4.12,1.55)
\psline(-4.12,1.55)(-0.16,2.13)
\psline(-0.16,2.13)(-1.9,3.57)
\psplot{-4.56}{0.88}{(-7.71-3.27*x)/-0.42}
\psline(-4.12,1.55)(-2.19,1.3)
\psline(-2.05,2.38)(-0.16,2.13)
\psdots(-1.9,3.57)
\rput[bl](-1.82,3.62){$A$}
\psdots(-4.12,1.55)
\rput[bl](-4.5,1.33){$B$}
\psdots(-0.16,2.13)
\rput[bl](-0.05,2.1){$C$}
\psdots(-2.05,2.38)
\rput[bl](-1.9,2.49){$K$}
\psdots(-2.19,1.3)
\rput[bl](-2.1,1.1){$H$}
\psdots[linecolor=darkgray](-2.12,1.84)
\rput[bl](-2,1.5){\black{$M$}}
\rput[bl](-2.2,0.5){\black{$\Delta$}}
\end{pspicture*}
\caption{}\label{fig:*2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
Type a quote from the document or the summary of an interesting point. You can position the text box anywhere in the document. Use the Drawing Tools tab to change the formatting of the pull quote text box.
Type a quote from the document or the summary of an interesting point. 

\caption{}\label{fig:*1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5.42,0.45)(1.2,4.02)
\psline(-3.36,2.93)(-4.38,0.97)
\psline(-4.38,0.97)(0.76,0.98)
\psline(0.76,0.98)(-3.36,2.93)
\psplot{-5.42}{1.2}{(-3.22-0.19*x)/-0.88}
\psline(-3.36,2.93)(-1.81,0.98)
\psline(-4.38,0.97)(-4.74,2.64)
\psline(-1.81,0.98)(-2.28,3.16)
\psline(0.76,0.98)(0.18,3.69)
\psline(-4.38,0.97)(-1.81,0.98)
\psline(-3.13,1.01)(-3.13,0.94)
\psline(-3.06,1.01)(-3.06,0.94)
\psline(-1.81,0.98)(0.76,0.98)
\psline(-0.56,1.02)(-0.56,0.94)
\psline(-0.49,1.02)(-0.49,0.94)
\psdots(-3.36,2.93)
\rput[bl](-3.48,3.09){$A$}
\psdots(-4.38,0.97)
\rput[bl](-4.5,0.6){$B$}
\psdots(0.76,0.98)
\rput[bl](0.66,0.6){$C$}
\psdots[linecolor=black](-1.81,0.98)
\rput[bl](-1.88,0.6){\black{$I$}}
\psdots[linecolor=darkgray](-4.74,2.64)
\rput[bl](-4.94,2.74){\black{$H$}}
\psdots[linecolor=black](0.18,3.69)
\rput[bl](0.08,3.78){\black{$K$}}
\rput[bl](0.8,3.5){\black{$\Delta$}}
\psdots[linecolor=black](-2.28,3.16)
\rput[bl](-2.32,3.25){\black{$L$}}
\end{pspicture*}
\caption{}\label{fig:*2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you thought of extracting your PSTricks code each to an minimal LaTeX-file, compile them seperately (maybe a `make` file or something like that) an include only images to your main document. I'm working with an equal workflow when having many PSTricks pictures and it keeps the code of the main document simple. And: You can create and improve each PSTricks picture seperately without recompiling the main document every time.

Comment: Thank you. I did so. How's about my two minipages?

Comment: I think the `minipage` environment is the most common to produce this kind of two columns. If your text is related to the picture, maybe try something like the `wrapfig` package, which allows to place the picture with a round floating text.

Comment: I've just realized you have a label for a figure in each `minipage`. If there are only images to be arranged, the `subfig` package might also be helpful.

Comment: Please repair my code. I really not good for insert picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to recreate your document, but I'm still not sure, what you really want to look the output like.

The main file has now this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  Type a quote from the document or the summary of an interesting
  point. You can position the text box anywhere in the document. Use
  the Drawing Tools tab to change the formatting of the pull quote
  text box.  Type a quote from the document or the summary of an
  interesting point.
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig1.pdf}
\caption{\label{fig:1} Caption of figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  Type a quote from the document or the summary of an interesting
  point. You can position the text box anywhere in the document. Use
  the Drawing Tools tab to change the formatting of the pull quote
  text box.  Type a quote from the document or the summary of an
  interesting point.
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig2.pdf}
\caption{\label{fig:2} Caption of figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`fig1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperwidth=6cm,paperheight=4cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.56,0.5)(0.88,4.07)
\psline(-1.9,3.57)(-4.12,1.55)
\psline(-4.12,1.55)(-0.16,2.13)
\psline(-0.16,2.13)(-1.9,3.57)
\psplot{-4.56}{0.88}{(-7.71-3.27*x)/-0.42}
\psline(-4.12,1.55)(-2.19,1.3)
\psline(-2.05,2.38)(-0.16,2.13)
\psdots(-1.9,3.57)
\rput[bl](-1.82,3.62){$A$}
\psdots(-4.12,1.55)
\rput[bl](-4.5,1.33){$B$}
\psdots(-0.16,2.13)
\rput[bl](-0.05,2.1){$C$}
\psdots(-2.05,2.38)
\rput[bl](-1.9,2.49){$K$}
\psdots(-2.19,1.3)
\rput[bl](-2.1,1.1){$H$}
\psdots[linecolor=darkgray](-2.12,1.84)
\rput[bl](-2,1.5){\black{$M$}}
\rput[bl](-2.2,0.5){\black{$\Delta$}}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

And `fig2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperwidth=7.5cm,paperheight=4cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=*,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5.42,0.45)(1.2,4.02)
\psline(-3.36,2.93)(-4.38,0.97)
\psline(-4.38,0.97)(0.76,0.98)
\psline(0.76,0.98)(-3.36,2.93)
\psplot{-5.42}{1.2}{(-3.22-0.19*x)/-0.88}
\psline(-3.36,2.93)(-1.81,0.98)
\psline(-4.38,0.97)(-4.74,2.64)
\psline(-1.81,0.98)(-2.28,3.16)
\psline(0.76,0.98)(0.18,3.69)
\psline(-4.38,0.97)(-1.81,0.98)
\psline(-3.13,1.01)(-3.13,0.94)
\psline(-3.06,1.01)(-3.06,0.94)
\psline(-1.81,0.98)(0.76,0.98)
\psline(-0.56,1.02)(-0.56,0.94)
\psline(-0.49,1.02)(-0.49,0.94)
\psdots(-3.36,2.93)
\rput[bl](-3.48,3.09){$A$}
\psdots(-4.38,0.97)
\rput[bl](-4.5,0.6){$B$}
\psdots(0.76,0.98)
\rput[bl](0.66,0.6){$C$}
\psdots[linecolor=black](-1.81,0.98)
\rput[bl](-1.88,0.6){\black{$I$}}
\psdots[linecolor=darkgray](-4.74,2.64)
\rput[bl](-4.94,2.74){\black{$H$}}
\psdots[linecolor=black](0.18,3.69)
\rput[bl](0.08,3.78){\black{$K$}}
\rput[bl](0.8,3.5){\black{$\Delta$}}
\psdots[linecolor=black](-2.28,3.16)
\rput[bl](-2.32,3.25){\black{$L$}}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

Which together leads to the following output:
[image: Screenshot of code above]

I hope, this is the result you wanted to achieve, otherwise please provide more information of how it should look like!